# Laravel QueueOn Error Connector

Tags: php, laravel

I am using `queueOn` with Laravel Homestead, but when I run it, it returns an error of "no connector".

My code:

```
Mail::queueOn('welcome', 'emails.verify_email', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
    $m->subject('Thank You for register ' . env('APP_NAME'))
      ->to($user->email);
});
```

When I try to run `php artisan queue:listen welcome` it returns an error of:

> InvalidArgumentException: No connector for []

But if I try to use `Mail::queue` and run only `php artisan queue:listen`, it works perfectly.

Is there any additional steps required if using `queueOn`?

---

I know one solution is to add a connection inside `queue.php`. But because I'm using Laravel Forge, I am trying not to mess with my current `queue.php`.

How can Forge handle queueOn? When I am using my default code and I put `queueOn` at Laravel Forge it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
queue:listen --queue=welcome
```

it works perfectly.